# Fade in elements with the same class only when their middle reach the viewport using jQuery waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I have a one page website consisting of many sections. I would like to make it more dynamic using jQuery Waypoints.

**What is should look like:**

Everytime an element with class *fade-in-element* enters the viewport (with some offset), it gets a special class that will animate (fade) the element in - **BUT ONLY the one element with the class & currently visible in the viewport.**

**What I have achieved:**

ALL elements with the class fade in when the first element with the class enters the viewport.

HTML:

```
<section>Some content</section>
<section>
    <div class="container fade-in-element">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"> SOME CONTENT </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"> SOME CONTENT </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"> SOME CONTENT </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="container fade-in-element">
        <h1 class="heading">HEADING</h1>

        <p>TEXT</p>
        <p>TEXT</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:
    .fade-in-element {
       opacity: 0;
    }

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        var inview = new Waypoint.Inview({
            element: $('.fade-in-wrap')[0],
            entered: function (direction) {
                $('.fade-in-element').addClass('animated2 fadeInLeft');
            },
            offset: '50%'
        });
    });
});
```

Anybody help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what you need

```
$('.fade-in-element').each(function(){
        var _this = this;
        var inview = new Waypoint({
            element: _this,
            handler: function (direction) {
                $(this.element).animate({'opacity': 1})
            },
            offset: '50%'
        });

        });
```

This is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5fhtzjqm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap it inside an if. You can check the window size with $(window).width and .height., and the current position with $(document).scrollTop. You can set up a bounding box with these values and check if the div is inside.

```
var top = $(document).scrollTop();
var height = $(window).height();
$('.fade-in-wrap').each(function(){
    var off = $(this).offset();
    if(off.top > top && off.top < top+height) {
        // Add the waypoint here. The element must be $(this)!
    }
});
```